# Javascript Refresh One Time Without Utilizing Hashtags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I'm using an orgy of javascript functions and scripts and they're conflicting a bit.

I have a page which already utilizes a hashtag in order to function correctly but one of the functions doesn't work unless the page is refreshed.

I've done a bit searching and have found a few ways to refresh the page but it checks to see there is a hashtag already in the url... and in my case I already do so it doesn't help.

I want to be able to refresh the page ONE time and that's all... without checking to see if there are hashtags in the url.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Utilize is spelled with two `i`s.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with no code?

Comment: What's this "hashtag" business?

Comment: @GGG I suspect OP is referring to a URL fragment identifier.

Comment: Why don't you save `refreshed` in a cookie?

Comment: excuse me for not being clear enough,
the url is like so: index.html#/shop
I was looking at this code but it didn't help as the url already has a hashtag:
    <script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
   </script>

Comment: @user1232698 a 'hashtag' is something on twitter, the word has no meaning outside of that domain. The part of a URL after a `#` is a fragment identifier

Comment: haha a bit embarrasing but thanks for the clarification

Comment: Is this on page load or on user interaction? Requiring a full page refresh on the first page load seems like a big red flag.

Comment: You see I'm using the FSS Full Screen SLiding Plugin, Which basically loads all the pages and allows you to slide from page to page without really leaving the first page. The jquery plugin I'm trying to use is jqzoom and isn't working unless the page utilizing it is refreshed. So i'm trying to refresh it everytime that slide (page) is shown.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
function doRefreshOnce(){
    if(localStorage["refreshed"]=="false"){
        localStorage["refreshed"]="true"
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by once?

Once ever? Once per user? Once per visit? What if a user has two tabs with the same page open? should it refresh in one of those tabs or both?

if you need **once ever** that needs to be handled server side.

**once per user** could be handled using local storage or a cookie

**once per "visit"** (i.e. once per set of tabs) could be handled by a cookie

**once per tab/visit** needs to be handled by the URL, be that using fragment identifiers or a querystring.